# Should I create a password for a user if they only will be using ssh key authentication?

Tags: security, ssh, password-management

I am adding a new user account (to a CentOS 6.2 box) which will only use ssh key authentication (with a strong key passphrase of course). I have disabled ssh password auth in sshd_config.

Should I even use `passwd` to setup a password for them?  Is there a security issue not creating a password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need a password if you will be only using SSH key authentication.

Even, if you set a password for this user, you can disable password authentication in `sshd_config` for specific users/groups.

Comment: You should also make sure null passwords are disabled in PAM configuration if you use empty passwords and don't want users to be able to login with username only.

Comment: I personnaly create my user accounts with 'adduser --disabled-password' (this is Debian specific), which makes sure there's only two way to get to this account : via SSH pubkey auth, or via local root then 'su'. It's obviously safer, although not safer than the user care for its private key (at least the weak part is where it is due, users, users....

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on if there was any other kind of interactive login they could use.

1. Physical access
2. su
3. Auth via `pam` using `/etc/passwd` for any other service

I would have thought it was good practice to at least set a password - if you are not 100% confident that another application could authenticate via `pam` using `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a password on login, but I do suggest using a passphrase on the private key on the user.  This means you'll have to use a forwarding agent, but then you provide security on the user's end if their machine is accessed or compromised.

Other than that potential issue, you should really be increasing security as there is no password for an attacker to even attempt to crack.